# Can I get location when gps is turned off and Internet is working?

Tags: android, networking, gps, location

My question is about getting location in android device when gps is turned off.

Comment: [I have post answer about this problem , please look into it hope it help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49999771/i-want-to-get-location-no-matter-whether-location-is-on-or-off/51625268#51625268)

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can, you only need to set your location request to PRIORITY_LOW_POWER https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.html#PRIORITY_LOW_POWER or PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.html#PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY

> The priority of the request is a strong hint to the LocationClient for which location sources to use. For example, PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY is more likely to use GPS, and PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY is more likely to use WIFI & Cell tower positioning, but it also depends on many other factors (such as which sources are available) and is implementation dependent.