# I want to get location no matter whether location is on or off

Tags: android

Is it possible to get the location, no matter my device location is on or off. I am not talking about network gps location that we normally pic up to to get my location but as per my knowledge this location will be thrown only only if the the device location is on. In simple, Is it possible to get the location when device location is off?

Comment: `Is it possible to get the location when device location is off?` - In short, no.

Comment: Your question is similar to this - "Is it possible to breath without mouth & nose"??

Comment: Sorry sir, I am new for stack over flow. And I am new for android as well,.

Comment: Know actually i don't know anything regarding this. Means i don't know how can i proceed?

Comment: If the GPS is off you can collect location from celuler network. Bujhsen vai? Otherwise it is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also facing this problem, now i end up for searching solution for this problem, with my own logic.

I have used FusedLocationProviderClient to get device location. and in LocationCallback onLocationResult overried which produce geo coords of the current location and that i saved SharedPreferences so whenever i required location i get that location through Shared Preferences. Also i first check is location is not ON then and only then i use Location saved into SharedPreferences, so it will not give me old location over new one. Hope it will someone in later future.

and Common.current_locaton is the Location class object.

LocationCallback : method

```
LocationCallback locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                super.onLocationResult(locationResult);

                Common.current_location = locationResult.getLastLocation();
                saveLocationToPrefs(locationResult.getLastLocation().getLatitude(),
                        locationResult.getLastLocation().getLongitude());
            }
        };
```

saveLocationToPrefs :

```
public void saveLocationToPrefs(double latitude, double longitude) {

        SharedPreferences locationPrefs = getSharedPreferences(LOCATION_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = locationPrefs.edit();
        editor.putFloat("latitude", (float) latitude);
        editor.putFloat("longitude", (float) longitude);
        editor.apply();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Is it possible to get an exact location without GPS? NO its not.

However it is possible to get COARSE location using `LocationManagers` `NETWORK_PROVIDER`

```
String locationProvider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationProvider, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

Without GPS, this is very rough estimation, and rellys on WiFi(s) and cellular data to provide you with location.

Comment: I get onProviderDisabled when I try to check location when GPS is turned off